# Rails, add ruby parameter to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a div, and I want it to be a link to other page. Usually we do it like this `link_to link`.

```
<% for post in @posts %>
   <%= link_to "Post", post %> # -> or <%= link_to(post) %>
<% end %>
```

But i need to whole div to be a link with js. So, i did:

```
<% for post in @posts %>
    <div class="post-on-main-page-<%= div_count %>" >
        <script>
           $(".post-on-main-page-<%= div_count %>").click(function(){
                window.location.href = "<%= link_to(post) %>";
              });
        </script>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But i doesn't work.

I need to `window.location.href = "<%= link_to(post) %>";` where post is a parameter, to give me a link to that post.

So how I can make this to work?

Comment: Why not just add a data attribute to the `div` and use that value to do your redirecting?

Comment: try this `window.location.href = " #{ link_to(post) }";

Comment: @BrenoPerucchi no that is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to` will generate a full `<a>` element

You should use `post_path(post)` or `post_url(post)` instead if you just want the path or url

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `block` to `link_to` helper like

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to post do %>
    <div class="post-on-main-page">
     <!-- Fill in your content -->
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will generate a div which will link to `posts#show` page.

Comment: Yes, I aware of that. But this is bad decision for me.